# Syntactic predicate is not working

Tags: antlr, predicate, antlr3

First rule never works. It should handle something like 'ID1.ID2.ID3.ID4.ID5'.
But other rules work as expected. What is wrong with it?

```
grammar testInt;

data_source:
     (ID '.' ID '.' ID ('.' ID)+)=>program_ref
    | (ID '.' ID '.' ID)=>var_ref
    | (ID '.' ID)=>program_ref
    | resource;

program_ref: ID ('.' ID)+;
var_ref:    ID '.' ID '.' ID;
resource:   ID;

ID:  (LETTER | ('_'(LETTER | DIGIT))) ('_'? (LETTER | DIGIT))*;
WSFULL:(' '|'\r'|'\t'|'\u000C'|'\n') {$channel=HIDDEN;};

fragment LETTER: (('a'..'z') | ('A'..'Z'));
fragment DIGIT: '0'..'9';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears ANTLR first tries to match `var_ref` before `program_ref` because the latter can potentially match just 2 `ID`'s where `var_ref` matches 3 and the parser matches tokens greedily.

I assume this is just a dummy (part of your) grammar: is there a real world problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Yes, it is a simplified version of the real problem i have with Structured Text language. Its grammar is quite ambiguous sometimes.

Comment: @Overdose, ah, that's something entirely different! :)